# Symfony2 - Upload, zip & encrypt a file once uploaded in the server

Tags: symfony, file-upload, zip

I have been implementing an entity in Symfony 2.2 in order to upload files to my server. I followed successfully the steps listed in

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html

However I need to implement an additional feature, which consists in saving the file along the entity, but not the original one, but the zipped & encrypted one, same as if I'd done that using the command line of linux and then uploaded the generated zip file. I mean, when I'm required to select in my form the file, I choose it as normal, but in the server it'd be stored a zip which contains that file instead of the file itself, and of course when downloading I want the zip as well, so the name in the table has to be the one of the zip file.

I guess it could be accomplished using system calls, allowing PHP to execute a zip command over the file, but I cannot figure it out how exactly. Any help?